# Linux variable value not working when running from script

Tags: linux, bash, unix

This is `MyScript.sh`

I want to execute a script as a text inside my script, I have tried to do it like so:

```
bash -c "
    #!/bin/bash
    STR=6
    echo $STR
"
```

Prints empty line.

I tried replacing `bash -c` with `sh -c` or `eval`, all options acts the same, why is that and how can it be solved?

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double quotes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using single quotes to avoid interpretation in the current shell:

```
$ cat myscript.sh
bash -c 'STR=6; echo $STR' 
./myscript.sh
6
```